# Powershell 4.0 and Excel 2013 | Bug | Work-a-round

Tags: excel, powershell

I am having troubles working with the new Powershell (4.0) and Excel 2013.
I know this is (or was) a common bug and I tried to work around it. But I failed. I can open an Excel-file and work on it without any problems. But it seems, that I can't close or save the workbook.

Additional information: I am in Europe - in Austria.

Additional information2: This Script works very well with Powershell 3.0 and Excel 2010.

Known bug, which shouldn't be in Excel 2013: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369/en-us

Why did I state this bug? Because my Script wouldn't even open the excel file in 2013 without the CurrentCulture part.

Code:

```
$Path     = "C:\Script\test.xls"
#Excelvar:
    $Excel               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Excel.Visible       = $true
    $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $newci = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]"en-US"
    [system.threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $newci
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $newci
        #Sheets:
        $Sheet1         = "1"
        $Sheet2         = "2"
        $Sheet3         = "3"
        $Sheet4         = "4"
        $Workbook       = $Excel.Workbooks.open($Path)

        #Sheets:
        $Sheet1 = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($Sheet1)
        $Sheet2 = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($Sheet2)
        $Sheet3 = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($Sheet3)
        $Sheet4 = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($Sheet4)
        #some reading and writing in the sheets
        ##############################
     #Saving and closing:
     $Workbook.SaveAs($Path)
     $Workbook.Close()
     $Excel.Quit()
     [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel) > $null
```

Errorcodes:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'SaveAs'.
At C:\Script\SCRIPT.ps1:620 char:5
+     $Workbook.SaveAs($Path)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Close'.
At C:\Script\SCRIPT.ps1:621 char:5
+     $Workbook.Close()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Thanks in advance!

If any further information is needed to help me solving this problem. Be free to ask. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to finally work around my problem. It is not very nice and I have no idea why my above stated did not work:

```
$newci = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]"en-US"
[system.threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $newci
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $newci
```

However, I could get the save function to work again with this:

```
Function Using-Culture (
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$culture = (throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}"),
[ScriptBlock]$script= (throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}"))
{
$OldCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
   trap 
   {
   [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
   }
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
Invoke-Command $script
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
}

Using-Culture en-US -script {
#SCRIPTBLOCK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Powershell 4 and office 2013 and I am using these lines to save and close:

```
#Define html code for Excel save to .htm.
$xlExcelHTML = 44
#################

#Save final result as an .xlsx file.
$b.SaveAs("$PathFileXML")
#####################

#Save final result as a .htm file
$b.SaveAs("$PathFileHTML",$xlExcelHTML)
###################################

#Close and quit Excel.
$b.Close()
##########

#Make sure excel and outlook is fully closed.
gps *Excel* | Stop-Process -force
#########################################
```

Answer (score 0):

A script I've been using for some time on Win7 with Excel 2013 and PoSH 4.0 started failing today, with a similar error, claiming that Activate [on a worksheet] was not a valid method. But running

```
$sheet | Get-Member
$sheet.Activate()      # failed here
```

showed that Activate *is* a valid member. Adding a sleep didn't make any difference.

What worked for me was running the **32-bit version** of PowerShell, available from Start --> All Programs --> Accessories --> Windows Powershell --> Windows Powershell (x86).

I applied a raft of Office 2013 updates this morning, perhaps one of them broke something.